# search for a specific file type with ack

Tags: ack

How can I use ack to search in files of a specific file type.

For example

```
ack -f .scss blah
acl -f .rb blah
```

Obviously the above does not work but how can I do this with ack?

Answer (score 35):

Use --type for this. To only search python files for example:

```
ack --type=python searchthis
```

List all the supported types with

```
ack --help=types  # ack 2.x
ack --help-types  # ack 3.x.x
```

If you want to create a custom type, add something like this to `~/.ackrc`:

```
--type-add=custom:ext:rb
--type-set
```

Then you can use --type=custom with ack to just search file with the .rb extension.

Answer (score 17):

```
find . -name '*.scss' | ack -x 'blah'
```

-x Read the list of files to search from STDIN.

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer:**

```
ack blah --css
```

**Long answer:**

You could add filetypes to your search to teach Ack to look only in those files. For example, lets associate **css** and **sass** extensions with a *"stylesheets"* short name:

```
ack --type-add=stylesheets:ext:css,sass
```

Now that you've teach Ack that you want to search on filetypes that you wanted to associate with the *"stylesheets"* short name, you can ask Ack to use that short name with:

```
ack --type-add=stylesheets:ext:css,sass --type=stylesheets blah
```

Or with the short way:

```
ack --type-add=stylesheets:ext:css,sass --stylesheets blah
```

Even in the short way, that's a lot to type for a search and that's the reason those kind of commands are better used on a configuration file like `~/.ackrc`, but I prefer to use them with an alias in my `~/.bashrc`.

But why does it works by default with `--type=css`, or `--css`? Because Ack have a default filenames groups that you can dump with `ack --dump`.

Using Ack version: 2.24